# How to skip cells with text?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm comparing values in two columns and deleting the row if a condition is met.  But sometimes there is text in a cell, and I can't get the program to ignore or skip over it.  This is basic code:

```
  Sub reorder()

Dim xrow As Integer
Dim incell As Range
Dim xrange As Range

Range("a5").End(xlDown).Select
xrow = ActiveCell.Row

 For xrow = xrow To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(xrow, 4).Value - Cells(xrow, 5).Value > 1 Then
            Rows(xrow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
 Next
End Sub
```

I've tried various things like the isnumeric function, but I always get errors or it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Can you give an example of the IsNumeric function not giving the results you're looking for? To me, it sounds like IsNumeric is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I agree, wrapping your `if` test with `If IsNumeric(Cells(xrow, 4).Value) And IsNumeric(Cells(xrow, 4).Value) Then   .....    End If` seems to work as you want, Herr Gambolputty.

Comment: related: If you are only interested in the cells starting at Range("A5").End(xlDown) (in reverse order), shouldn't your loop be For xrow = xrow To **5** Step -1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work smoothly now :

```
Sub reorder()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim wS As Worksheet

Set wS = ActiveSheet
With wS
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 4).Value) And IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 5).Value) Then
            If .Cells(i, 4).Value - .Cells(i, 5).Value > 1 Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Dankeschön! Perfect.  I believe my problem was with the syntax - I was trying to do "If IsNumeric([cells]) = False Then...".  I have a lot to learn, but this seems to be a great place to do that, thanks again.